# Accessing to Odoo data with Django REST API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, odoo, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to build a Django REST API e-commerce by retrieving data from Odoo, for that I need first of all to connect to odoo database.
Any idea of how to do that !?

PS: with XML-RPC it was easy but I want to to work with REST
 Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Odoo is usually extended internally via modules, but many of its features and all of its data are also available from the outside for external analysis or integration with various tools. Part of the Models API is easily available over XML-RPC and accessible from a variety of languages.

Read more : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/webservices/odoo.html

Example of XML-RPC by using Django rest framework:

```
    import xmlrpclib
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    
    db = '<DB-NAME>'
    url = '<your-host-name:8069>'
    
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
    common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
    
    def get_uid():
        username = '<your-odoo-username>'
        password = '<your-odoo-password>'
        uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
        return uid, password

    # create default execute method (Odoo Xmlrpc)
    def execute(*args):
        uid = get_uid()[0]
        password = get_uid()[1]
        return models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, *args)

    # Rest Api for get contact list of odoo with name only
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def get_contacts_list(request):
        contacts = execute('res.partner', 'search_read', [[]], {'fields':['name']})
        return Response({'result': contacts, 'status_code': 200})
```